# Cannot Delete the Records in Python

Tags: python

i am creating a simple crud application in python.i ran into the problem with couln't delete records.what i tried so far i attached below i don't know what was a problem. i got the error on the console
**1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s'**

```
def delete():
    studid = e1.get()

    mysqldb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",database="smschool")
    mycursor=mysqldb.cursor()

    try:
       sql = "delete from record where id = %s"
       val = (studid)
       mycursor.execute(sql, val)
       mysqldb.commit()
       lastid = mycursor.lastrowid
       messagebox.showinfo("information", "Record Deleteeeee successfully...")

       e1.delete(0, END)
       e2.delete(0, END)
       e3.delete(0, END)
       e4.delete(0, END)
       e1.focus_set()

    except Exception as e:

       print(e)
       mysqldb.rollback()
       mysqldb.close()
```

Comment: Try making `val` a tuple: `val = (studid,)`.

Comment: @khelwood Wouldn't it be more Pythonic to just `val = studid,` ?

Comment: thanks sir workinggggggggggggggggggggggg

Comment: @khelwood Avoiding unnecessary characters is always favorable. Like `if condition:` vs `if (condition):` vs `if ((condition)):` and so on.

Comment: @abe To me `(studid,)` is easier to identify as a tuple at a glance. The comma in `val = studid,` is easy to miss. But opinions may differ.

Comment: @khelwood Yeah I agree with the readability aspect

Answer (score -3, accepted):

On the line `sql = "delete from record where id = %s"` you haven't told it which id it should delete.
Try

```
id = 1
sql = "delete from record where id = %d" % (id)
```

Take a look at https://pyformat.info/ for information about using %s or %d

Comment: tk.Label(root, text="Student Crud System").place(x=400, y=5)    this label font size how to increase please tell any one

Comment: The OP's code had the right approach; this is the wrong approach. You should not use `%` or otherwise string formatting to insert something that can be given as a query parameter. `mycursor.execute(sql, val)` (where `val` is a tuple containing your id) is safer from sql injection.